# Creating rectangle on centroid point by map click event ol5

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to develop a web portal using ol5 API where user click on map and then it takes map click event coordinates as centroid of rectangle and create a rectangle of particular height and width.

Here is the code to create square

```
image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
        fill: fill,
        points: 4,
        radius: 30,
        angle: Math.PI / 4
    })
```

But I want to create rectangle with center point, height and width.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, it is. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: What software or language are you using to develop with?

Comment: i am using openlayer 5 API.

Comment: Are height and width in pixels or meters?

Comment: height and width in meter.

Comment: Because this question was closed and edited before being reopened there is now a duplicate with an answer  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323649/create-rectangle-with-center-point-height-and-width-ol5-api

Comment: Ok Mike sir. thanks a lot.