# Create rectangle with center point , height and width ol5 API

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to develop a web portal using ol5 API where user click on map and then it takes map click event coordinates as centroid of rectangle and create a rectangle of particular height and width.

Here is the to create square

```
image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
        fill: fill,
        points: 4,
        radius: 30,
        angle: Math.PI / 4
    })
```

But I want to create rectangle with center point , height and width. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegularShape only works for regular polygons.  One way to display a point feature as a rectangle with different width and height would be to use a geometry function to produce a polygon from the point coordinates, for example

```
new ol.style.Style({
  geometry: function(feature) {
     var coordinate = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
     return ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent([coordinate[0]-width/2, coordinate[1]-height/2, coordinate[0]+width/2, coordinate[1]+height/2])
  }
  fill: fill
  stroke: stroke
})
```

or a style function

```
function(feature, resolution) {
  var coordinate = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  return new ol.style.Style({
    geometry: ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent([
      coordinate[0] - width*resolution/2,
      coordinate[1] - height*resolution/2,
      coordinate[0] + width*resolution/2,
      coordinate[1] + height*resolution/2
    ]),
    fill: fill
    stroke: stroke
  })
}
```

Comment: i did not understand how to use this code?

Comment: is height and width is in meter for this one "coordinate[0]-width/2"?

Comment: In that case width and height would be map units, so it would scale with the view.  To set a size in pixels you would need to multiple by resolution, which would need a style function.

Comment: i am using your code like this function myCallback(evt){
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  console.log("coordinate = "+coordinate);
       
  feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent([coordinate[0]-width/2, coordinate[1]-height/2, coordinate[0]+width/2, coordinate[1]+height/2]));
  //ADD RECTANGLE
  vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
  
    }